# mdadm : difference in metadata versions

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

Can anyone tell me the difference between the different metadata versions for mdadm?

When I try the command `mdadm --examine /dev/sda1`, I can't seem to find "preferred superblocks" on version 1.2. This field shows up in metadata version 0.9.

Is there a way to get such metadata information? Or is the output of `mdadm --examine` just the information I'm going to get for version 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

All the differences are covered here RAID wiki on kernel.org. The page is titled: [RAID superblock formats](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#A_Note_about_kernel_autodetection_of_different_superblock_formats). The version 0.90 and 1.2 formats of the superblock are covered there as well.

The on-disk layouts are covered there as well.

- [The version-1 superblock format on-disk layout](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#A_Note_about_kernel_autodetection_of_different_superblock_formats)

Comment: There's no information about the metadata structure for 0.90 to compare them with. I'm trying find the "preferred minor" field but isn't found in the metadata for version 1.* from the document provided.